# CakePHP and handling parameters in REST

Tags: php, web-services, rest, cakephp

So first, let me explain what I am trying to do.

I have successfully implemented a SOAP service with CakePHP, using this tutorial:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Marcelius/2009/02/10/soap-services-in-cakephp

That part works great. I can send and receive XML messages via SOAP, and I have about 6 controllers with a bunch of different functions setup to handle those requests.

What I want to have is this same application also able to handle requests via REST. So far, I've managed to add mapResources() and parseExtentions() to my routes.php file and it's working great for functions that don't require any parameters to be passed in to work properly, i.e. I can go to a URL like

localhost/directory/controller_name/function_name.xml

... and I'll get back all the results, and I barely have to touch my existing code to get it to work.

However, I am having real difficulty getting this to work when the function needs some input parameter to work properly -- some of these variables can get rather complex too, like an array.

I've read about how you can use file_get_contents("php://input") to fetch and parse the incoming request body but that really doesn't seem to work too well, because I have to go back and change all my existing code to fetch from that source, and every function call throws a warning for missing parameters.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? What would be the best way to handle this situation with CakePHP?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of answered my own question today, after struggling for awhile...

I ended up passing in the function parameters via GET, but this still required them to be passed directly to the controller functions as a stdClass, as that is how PHP's SOAP classes handles parameters, so that is what the existing code is expecting. I was able to make a custom cakeroute class which looks like this:

```
class GetRestParamRoute extends CakeRoute {
function parse($url) {
    $params = parent::parse($url);

    if(count($_GET) > 1){


        $obj = new stdClass();
        foreach($_GET as $get_var_name => $get_var_value){

            if($get_var_name == "url") continue;

            $obj->$get_var_name = $get_var_value;
        }


        $params['pass'][] = $obj;
    }

    return $params;
}
```

And then in routes.php

```
        App::import('Lib', 'routes/GetRestParamRoute');
    Router::connect('/:controller/:action', array(), 
            array('routeClass' => 'GetRestParamRoute'));
```

So what happens here is that all URL requests are passed to the custom route class, which in turn looks at the GET variables, and if they are not the url itself, they are added as members to an stdclass which is then added to the parameter's passed variables, and is passed into the controller function when it is called. I then handled the response as the Cake book declares the 'simple setup', i.e. added this to my routes.php

```
        Router::mapResources("myController");
    Router::parseExtensions('xml');
```

And voila! Add an XML view for each controller, and now all function calls can be made via GET and returns as RESTful XML.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to get the parameters from an arbitrary request would be to use the cake-style conventions to get the parameters. You could access `$this->params['url']` from within your controller instead of using the `$_GET` superglobal array.

http://localhost/CAKE_DIR/profilePhotos.json?param1=123&param2=456

`$this->params['url']` would break the URL and parameters up like so:

`{"ext":"json","url":"profilePhotos.json","param1":"123","param2":"456"}`

Comment: In normal circumstances this is how a sane person would do that. But it does not work in this case. The existing code is fitted to handle soap requests, so any controller function with parameters is expecting just one stdClass as input. If I did it your way, I would have to go back and change ALL of my existing code to manually grab all the variables from $this->param['url'] rather than just having the route figuring it out, and also match the function signature.